# Convert hash to string in ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

```
input = {:a=>{:type=>"list", :values=>[{:type=>"b", :id=>"123"}, {:type=>"b", :id=>"456"}]}}
```

output should be as follows

```
{:new_name=>"123,456"}
```

I tried using inject like this.Not sure what to include inside the block

```
input.tap do |e|
 e[:a].try(:[], :values).inject({}) do |h, obj|
   h[:new_name] = **
 end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You are given:

```
input = {:a=>{:type=>"list",
              :values=>[{:type=>"b", :id=>"123"},
                        {:type=>"b", :id=>"456"}
                       ]
             }
        }
```

Let's first simplify:

```
a = input[:a][:values]
  #=> [{:type=>"b", :id=>"123"},
       {:type=>"b", :id=>"456"}]
```

Now pull out the strings we need:

```
b = a.map { |h| h[:id] }
  #=> ["123", "456"]
```

Lastly,

```
{ "new_name" => b.join(',') }
  #=> {"new_name"=>"123,456"}
```

Putting this all together,

```
{ "new_name" => input[:a][:values].map { |h| h[:id] }.join(',') }
  #=> {"new_name"=>"123,456"}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{:new_name => input.values.first[:values].map{|hash| hash[:id]}.join(',')}
# => {:new_name=>"123,456"}
```

This works only if your input hash has always the same structure.